# How to get the user's wallpaper

Tags: c#, windows

As the title
I would like the effect like UAC's background

Here is a code I found from web.

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace cleandesktop
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uAction, uint uParam, StringBuilder lpvParam, uint init);
        const uint SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0073;
        static void Main(string[]) args
        {
            StringBuilder wallPaperPath = new StringBuilder(200);
            if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, 200, wallPaperPath, 0))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(wallPaperPath.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code get the path of the wallpaper picture, but this code only works when users hadn't delete their wallpaper picture.

Comment: What exactly would you expect the result to be if the user *has* deleted their wallpaper picture?

Comment: I wish I could also get their wallpaper

Answer (score 1):

[`PaintDesktop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-paintdesktop)

> The PaintDesktop function fills the clipping region in the specified device context with the desktop pattern or wallpaper.

Comment: Could you give me the C# code please?
I don't know how to use this API

Comment: You need to pinvoke it but to do that you need a HDC to the destination (your window or a bitmap).